# Strangeness in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've got a simple if statement that is behaving very strangely. When I assign a value to an `attr_accessor` within the if statement that it wipes out the value. Here's a concise example that demonstrates the issue.

```
class FName
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :file_ext

  def full_name
    puts "initial file_ext value: #{file_ext}"
    if file_ext.nil?
      file_ext = ".default"
    end
    puts "new file_ext value: #{file_ext}"
    "#{name}#{file_ext}"
  end
end

f = FName.new
f.name = "foo"
f.file_ext = ".txt"
puts f.full_name
```

This outputs the following:

```
initial file_ext value: .txt
new file_ext value:
foo
```

Which is not at all what you'd expect. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Note that I can reproduce this problem in both Ruby 2.0.0-p247 and Ruby 2.1.1_1. Also note that if I remove the line `file_ext = ".wrong"` then the code sample behaves as expected when file_ext is not nil, but of course I then don't have a way to provide a default value when file_ext is nil.

I've tried putting `puts` statements into the if block, and (as expected) they print nothing. When I remove the line `f.file_ext = ".txt"` then I get the output:

```
initial file_ext value:
new file_ext value: .default
foo.default
```

One last note: I'm hoping to provide the default value lazily like this because in my real code the value is computed and I'm hoping to avoid the computation unless necessary.

Hopefully someone out there can tell my why this is happening!

Comment: As the answers have explained, the problem is that Ruby is assuming you want `file_extent` to be a local variable. You have to tell Ruby you mean it to be the accessor. Two ways of doing that are `self.file_extent = ".default"` and `send(:file_ext=, ".default")`.  A little odd?  Perhaps. [You also need to do this to distinguish the method `class` from the keyword `class`, as in `if(self.class == String)...`.] Lastly, any local variable created between `if` and `end` is still in scope after `end`, just as if it were created before `if` or after `end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def full_name
  puts "initial file_ext value: #{file_ext}" # line 2
  if file_ext.nil?
    self.file_ext = ".default"     # update this line (Line 4)
  end
  puts "new file_ext value: #{file_ext}"
  "#{name}#{file_ext}"
end
```

Line 4 won't actually execute, however, the Ruby source file analyzer will treat `file_ext = ".default"` as a local variable assignment and create a local variable after executing the `if` statement. However, since the assignment didn't actually get called, the local variable won't have value stored.

On line 2, Ruby searches the variable `file_ext` at local scope, when it fails, it trys to invoke the method `file_ext` binded to `self` and retrieved the method from `attr_accessor`.

Comment: This makes sense, but leaves me with questions about scoping (see my comment on the other answer).

Comment: @neuronaut `if`/`unless` statements do not have scope in Ruby. And the correct term for “source file analyzer” is “parser”.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quirk of Ruby.  The line

```
      file_ext = ".default"
```

must be changed to

```
      self.file_ext = ".default"
```

Without the `self.`, a local variable `file_ext` is silently created in lieu of the accessor call you intended.

It is created even though the `if` body does not execute due to `Ruby` variable declaration semantics. It automatically gets the value `nil`, which prints as an empty string.  Here's an extract from the [Ruby RDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html):

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs:

```
     a = 0 if false # does not assign to a
     p local_variables # prints [:a]
     p a # prints nil
```

I share your pain, having lost in aggregate a couple of hours of my life to this "feature" of Ruby syntax.  Much of Ruby is really beautiful, but this is bad language design.

Comment: I see that this fixes the issue, but why is a local variable being created? it's inside an `if` statement, so that code shouldn't be executed, right? And when it does, should't the variable be local to the if block? Maybe I'm not understanding scoping in Ruby...